# Questions on an implementation of Radix sort in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bit-manipulation, radix-sort

The following Radix sort does four passes of counting sort (256 buckets, 32-bit integers, starting from lowest significant digits), taken from [Sedgewick's Algorithms textbook](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/51radix/LSD.java.html).

```
public class LSD {
    private final static int BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;

    // LSD sort an array of integers, treating each int as 4 bytes
    // assumes integers are nonnegative
    // [ 2-3x faster than Arrays.sort() ]
    public static void sort(int[] a) {
    int BITS = 32;                 // each int is 32 bits 
    int W = BITS / BITS_PER_BYTE;  // each int is 4 bytes
    int R = 1 << BITS_PER_BYTE;    // each bytes is between 0 and 255
    int MASK = R - 1;              // 0xFF

    int N = a.length;
    int[] aux = new int[N];

    for (int d = 0; d < W; d++) {         

        // compute frequency counts
        int[] count = new int[R+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {           
            int c = (a[i] >> BITS_PER_BYTE*d) & MASK;
            count[c + 1]++;
        }

        // compute cumulates
        for (int r = 0; r < R; r++)
            count[r+1] += count[r];

        // for most significant byte, 0x80-0xFF comes before 0x00-0x7F
        if (d == W-1) {
            int shift1 = count[R] - count[R/2];
            int shift2 = count[R/2];
            for (int r = 0; r < R/2; r++)
                count[r] += shift1;
            for (int r = R/2; r < R; r++)
                count[r] -= shift2;
        }

        // move data
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int c = (a[i] >> BITS_PER_BYTE*d) & MASK;
            aux[count[c]++] = a[i];
        }

        // copy back
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = aux[i];
    }
}
```

I understand most of the code except for this part:

```
if (d == W-1) {
    int shift1 = count[R] - count[R/2];
    int shift2 = count[R/2];
    for (int r = 0; r < R/2; r++)
        count[r] += shift1;
    for (int r = R/2; r < R; r++)
        count[r] -= shift2;
}
```

What's the purpose of this segment of code? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code block does exactly what the comment says:

> for most significant byte, 0x80-0xFF comes before 0x00-0x7F

The reason for this is: since you are using `int`, so the most significant bit is the **sign** bit. Therefore numbers with the most significant byte in the range `0x80-0xFF` are negative numbers, so should be placed before positive numbers, which has the most significant byte in the range of `0x00-0x7F`.

If you are asking how the code block achieves it, here is a brief idea:

Since you understood how data is moved, so I assume you understood what does `count[]` do in the entire code. In the code block, `R` is the upper bound, which is `0xFF + 1`, and `R / 2` is `0x7F + 1`. Therefore `count[R] - count[R / 2]` is the total number in the range of `0x80` to `0xFF`. Therefore by adding a shift of `count[R] - count[R / 2]` to `count[0 .. R / 2]` and subtracting it from `count[R / 2 .. R]` will help numbers ranged in `0x00` to `0x7F` have higher `count` value than numbers ranged in `0x80` to `0xFF`, which results in **0x80-0xFF comes before 0x00-0x7F** ultimately.

Lastly, you may be curious: if the first bit is sign bit, why `11111111` is bigger than `10000001`? Isn't that `-(127) < -(1)`? This is because in the computer system, we are using [2's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) instead of **signed integers**, therefore `11111111` actually means `-1`, and `10000001` actually means `-127`.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! In this case, this segment of code actually works for `int a[]` that includes nonnegative integers (as opposed to the code author's assumption on the line 4-5 comment)?